# How to ensure that there is at least one instance of my nested serializer in Django Rest Framework for creation?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Rather than a long explication, some code :

My main serializer `OrderSerializer` and the nested serializer `OffersSerializer`:

```
class OffersSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    offers = OffersSerializer(many=True, required=True)
```

With that I can POST data like this :

```
{
    "offers": []
}
```

This is valid for DRF, but I would like to check there is at least one offer, so for example:

```
{
    "offers": [{"id": 1, "quantity": 200}]
}
```

How can I ensure that there is at least one offer ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def validate_offers(self, attrs):
        if len(attrs) == 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('at least one offer required')
        return attrs
```

Comment: the most elegant way to do this is remove `blank=True` for offers field in your Order model.

Comment: Actually this serializer is not linked to a model.

Comment: :(  looked mistakenly,You're not using ModelSerializer

Answer (score 0):

Work with the Manger oder your serzializer-model, e.g.:

```
if (mySerializerModel.objects.all()[0] != None):
    # some code
    pass
```

There are other possibilities to check this. I think there is even a `count()` method for your managers.:

```
if (mySerializerModel.objects.all().count() > 0):
    # some code
    pass
```

Further there are `mySerializerModel.objects.get(<id>)` if you know the id. There might be other possibilites to check that. Just have a look at the [django queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/).